# Jenkins pipeline error: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks

I deployed Jenkins in EKS with standard installation/plugins. I'm getting this error when I use the dockerTool in my pipeline "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        go 'go-1.21'
        dockerTool 'docker-latest'
    }
    environment {
        GO111MODULE='on'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/AdminTurnedDevOps/GoWebAPI.git'
                sh 'go test ./...'
            }
        }
        stage('Building our image') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t adminturneddevops/go-webapp-sample .'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any insights or alternatives on how to run docker build in jenkins pipeline is highly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm expecting to get resolution or alternatives to my issues.

Comment: This error usually reports that Docker service (Docker daemon) is not started. Do you have Docker installed in the environment of Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, I've installed docker plugins on Jenkins.

Comment: You need to check if docker is installed not on your Jenkins *master*, but on the agent as well. Seeing `agent any`, this could be any of your slaves.

Comment: I haven't setup any agent yet in my Jenkins yet, so all jobs runs in my Jenkins master.

Comment: Docker has a client/server architecture.  It's not enough to install the Jenkins Docker plugin, you also need to install Docker itself.  I've linked this question to another one describing that issue in more detail, though "on EKS" will bring some complications.